# Weird section for bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I am using a template of a conference, but I get a weird layout.
The type of text is an article, with double column. The template is downloadable from this page: http://www.aimi-musica.org/?page_id=3208

Let's suppose that normal text is 10pt, while the \section{} titles are 12pt.

When I arrive to the end, I type \bibliography{some bibliography}.
This creates an empty section (only the number of the section with an asterisk 12pt) in the centre of the column, and then the word "References" on the left of the column with text fontsize.

I attach a picture of the problem.

[image]

---

By writing:

```
\section*{Reference}

\bibliography{cim2018template}
```

I get the problem twice! :D

[image]

---

This code reproduces just the issue:

```
% -----------------------------------------------
% Template for CIM 2018
% adapted from the template for CIM 2016
% which was adapted itself from the template for SMC 2010
% -----------------------------------------------

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cim2018}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[square, numbers]{natbib}
%user defined variables
%\def\papertitle{Punti di discontinuità e cadenze spaziali: due concetti sperimentali per lo sviluppo di nuove teorie musicali}
\def\papertitle{Points of discontinuity and spatial cadences: two experimental concepts for the development of musical theory}
\def\author{Luca Danieli}

% adds the automatic
% Saves a lot of ouptut space in PDF... after conversion with the distiller
% Delete if you cannot get PS fonts working on your system.

% pdf-tex settings: detect automatically if run by latex or pdflatex
\newif\ifpdf
\ifx\pdfoutput\relax
\else
   \ifcase\pdfoutput
      \pdffalse
   \else
      \pdftrue
\fi
\fi

\ifpdf % compiling with pdflatex
  %\pdfcompresslevel=9
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  \usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
  \usepackage{subcaption}
  \usepackage[pdftex,
    pdftitle={\papertitle},
    pdfauthor={\firstauthor},
    bookmarksnumbered, % use section numbers with bookmarks
    pdfstartview=XYZ % start with zoom=100% instead of full screen; especially useful if working with a big screen :-)
   ]{hyperref}
  %\usepackage[figure,table]{hypcap}

  % put here are the names of the the PDF figures for the PDFlatex
  \global \def\fig1{figure.pdf}

\else % compiling with latex
  \usepackage[dvips]{epsfig,graphicx}
  %define the EPS figures here as PDFlatex does not accept them
  \usepackage[dvips,
    bookmarksnumbered, % use section numbers with bookmarks
    pdfstartview=XYZ % start with zoom=100% instead of full screen
  ]{hyperref}
  % hyperrefs are active in the pdf file after conversion
  %\usepackage[figure,table]{hypcap}

  \global \def\fig1{figure.eps}

\fi

%setup the hyperref package - make the links black without a surrounding frame
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    urlcolor=black
}


% Title.
% ------
\title{\papertitle}

% Single address
% To use with only one author or several with the same address
% ---------------
%\oneauthor
% {\firstauthor} {Affiliation1 \\ {\tt \href{mailto:author1@server.org}{author1@server.org}}}
% 
%
%Two addresses
%--------------
% \twoauthors
%  {\firstauthor} {Affiliation1 \\ {\tt \href{mailto:author1@server.org}{author1@server.org}}}
%  {\secondauthor} {Affiliation2 \\ {\tt \href{mailto:author2@server.org}{author2@server.org}}}

% Three addresses
% --------------
 \oneauthor
   {\author} {University of Birmingham \\ Dep. of Electroacoustic Music \\ Birmingham (UK) \\ {\tt \href{mailto:lxd430@bham.ac.uk}{lxd430@bham.ac.uk}} \\ {\tt \href{mailto:dnllcu@gmail.com}{dnllcu@gmail.com}}}


% ***************************************** the document starts here ***************
\begin{document}
%
\section*{Reference}

\bibliography{cim2018template}

\end{document}
```

I am sure it will be probably something related to the packages used

Comment: Oooh, a mystery. Is that template XYZ from ABC? Or ABC from Wombat? Might as well be Alpaca from Ant. A lot of guessing here. Nobody can answer.

Comment: Which template exactly? Looks like perhaps the class hasn't implemented unnumbered sections (`\section*{..}`), but `\bibliography` uses `\section*{References}` to make the heading. If no starred version of `\section` is defined, it would grab the `*`, use that as the section heading, and then print `References`. But if you want a fix, you should show us a code example. (Edit: excuse Johannes, he is a bit fed up with "templates".)

Comment: The template is called cim2018template, and it is released by the CIM conference on the model released by the SMC conference. It is downloadable from here: http://www.aimi-musica.org/?page_id=3208

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information (and wouldn't hurt to add a proper [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) as well).

Comment: @TorbjørnT., added!

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Come on, it's indeed the package natbib. I could probably get that by myself, if I had tried to clean the code completely. Sorry to disturb you all, and thanks!

Comment: Yes and no. The `cim2018` package redefefines `\section` so that it doesn't allow for `\section*`, as I described above. Then perhaps `natbib` redefines `\bibliography` to use `\section*`. So yes, removing `natbib` solves the problem, but you could argue the culprit is `cim2018.sty`. (And indeed, making a proper MWE will often point you directly to the problem.)

Comment: Don't know what's a MWE, but thanks @TorbjørnT. for the times you have spent for looking into the issue!

Comment: MWE  = minimal working example, cf. my previous comment.

Comment: `\def\author`? Oh, dear.